# How to reduce the size of Bert model(checkpoint/model_state.bin) using pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, data-science-model, bert

I used `torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic` to reduce the model size but it is reducing my prediction Accuracy score.

I'm using that model file inside the Flask and doing some real time predictions, Due to the large size i'm facing issues while predicting. So could anyone please help me on reducing the bert model size using pytorch and guide me on who to do the real time predictions.

Comment: `Due to the large size i'm facing issues while predicting`. Can you describe those issues?

Comment: Thanks for the response, i faced issues like taking time for prediction, loading large size models in the flask, memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

Are you reusing an existing Bert model or are you training it from scratch?

In all the cases, you can apply several solutions to your model:

- Use [distill Bert](https://github.com/sigmeta/distillation-BERT) instead
- [Pruning](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/pruning_tutorial.html)
- [Freezing](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/prototype/torchscript_freezing.html#:%7E:text=Freezing%20is%20the%20process%20of,in%20the%20resulting%20Frozen%20module.)
- Convert it to [ONNX](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/master/onnxruntime/python/tools/transformers/notebooks/PyTorch_Bert-Squad_OnnxRuntime_GPU.ipynb)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm using `bert_model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')` and from that written the classifier and trained with my own data set.

Comment: Have you tried distill Bert? For information, if you train it from scratch only with your data, you can reduce its size considerably.

Comment: https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased

Comment: Note: I'm also developing a flask service with NLP models. I've written an article about it that might answers some questions about model optimization: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-create-your-first-large-scale-aiaas-1cd2225fd0f2